# How to do the animated parametric plot with non-static trail

Tags: animation, plot, parametric-equations

[image: annotated image of the plot]

Application used: [everycircuit](https://everycircuit.com/app) 
Example circuits used (the book icon in the left sidebar): 
: "LED Array", "RC step response"

So,

- the image is of a parametric plot of some quantities on vertical axis (legend indicated by #3 in image), and one quantity on horizontal axis (legend indicated by #2)
- in this, there's one parameter with respect to which all values are changing (which is time)
- in the plot, the trail of values is kept for some time then it is erased - the keeping behaviour helps when the system is stable, and the erasing helps a lot to declutter the plot and zoom into the new relevant area/scale when the system changes its characteristics

How to do this animation in other code based data analysis software? like python/octave/julia etc?

Animation i.e.

- the values changing with change in the parameter (i.e. the normal plot),
- but the trail shown for only some time (hence, non-static)
- while still retaining some way to change the parameter, and see which point corresponds to that (also known as "track" the plot)

Comment: Is this a programming question? [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) If not, you should delete this and ask, instead, on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: hi, is there some move question mechanism in here? or do i have to manually do this?

Comment: You can hit the Flag under your question and ask a moderator to do it.

Comment: i have narrowed down to only focus on the topic related to programming.